# Html.RenderAction<MyController> - does not have type parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, renderaction

I'm trying to use RenderAction in the following way:

`'<% Html.RenderAction( x => x.ControllerAction() ); %>'`

as seen here:

http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2008/11/24/renderpartial-vs-renderaction.aspx

and here:

http://eduncan911.com/blog/html-renderaction-for-asp-net-mvc-1-0.aspx

but I keep getting an error about the method not having type parameters. also in MSDN I see there is no documentation for it, and also checking the MVC source code I can't find anything.
I'm using the latest ASP.Net MVC (2.0 RTM)

is this feature no longer available? how can I use it?

thanks.

Comment: I checked futures as well and couldn't find it. could be that I missed it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no `Html.RenderAction` overload which accepts an expression in the ASP.Net MVC 2 RTM. So no, it's not available.

Comment: were there such overloads in the past? where did they go?

Comment: It's in Futures (http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742).  Import the Microsoft.Web.Mvc namespace, and you'll see them as extension methods hanging off of HtmlHelper.  The particular class that contains the extension methods is Microsoft.Web.Mvc.LinkExtensions.

These helpers are buggy and unsupported, so use them at your own risk.